# Tag synonym request: [persistent] to [persistence]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Remap [persistent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/persistent) to [persistence](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/persistence)

Both deal with persistence issues on Live USB. While [persistent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/persistent) has more posts I propose to make [persistence](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/persistence) (or persistance??) the main tag anyhow.

Suggestion for a tag wiki text:

> This deals with problems of keeping settings on live media.